# How to convert a string with space between the lines to a new string with out any line spaces

Tags: java, string

I have a string with space between the lines, like this:

```
String name = "This is the \n example of the string";
```

And I want to convert the string to this: `"This is the example of the string"`, without any spaces between the lines.
How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

`replaceAll` takes regex as first argument. In regex

- `\s` represents any whitespace - `\n` and `\r` are also included here. (BTW, to pass this regex to Java regex engine you will need to write it as `"\\s"` because `\` is special character in String so it needs to be escaped)
- `+` is quantifier representing "once or more" so
- `"\\s+"` represents one or more whitespace.

So `replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` will match match substirng containing one or more whitespaces like
`" \n "` and replace it with one space.

Answer (score -2):

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\n","");
name = name.replaceAll("[ ]+"," ");
```

Comment: the first line replace all \n with empty string right?and why did you write \\n and not \n? and what is the second line does?